# Go Daddy SMTP Error - SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, smtp, office365, godaddy-api

I am using php mailer to generate and send automatic e-mails when a form is submitted on my web site which is run on GoDaddy. Since GoDaddy has changed their e-mail platform from Workspace to Office365 last week, my website stopped sending automatic e-mails, because host was changed, and since new host (Office365) required new settings (like different port number and SMTPSecure info). So I made some changes on my php code as following:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Username = 'user@username.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = ('from@from.com');
$mail->addAddress('to@destination.com');
$mail->FromName = 'myname';
```

After changing host to office365, SMTPSecure info to 'tls' and Port number to 587, I started to get the following error:

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: An attempt was made to access
> a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013)
> 2022-10-08 08:35:07 SMTP connect() failed

I have tried following ports: 25, 80, 465 and 587.
I have tried following SMTPSecure types: 'tls', 'ssl', 'StartTLS'. But none of them worked.

I have also enabled SMTP authentication as advised in other answers. And tried all the alternative code snippets given in other questions but none of them worked.

Also, I have tried accessing my e-mail account and send automatic e-mail from Powershell. And it worked, so I think there is no issue with the e-mail account that I am using. So I'm thinking issue might be GoDaddy specific.

I have checked almost all of the questions and answers on websites but none of them worked. So I desperately need help to resolve this issue and start using my websites back. Any answer will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe SMTP_AUTH is not enabled for the mailbox being used, and you need to enable it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365

Comment: I did actually. From the dashboard->advanced settings on godaddy,  and then turned on SMTP authentication. If that is what you mean. also in microsoft exchange's settings, my SMTP auth protocol is set as on.

Comment: I have a new error which might be helpful for the case 'SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Your message wasn't delivered because your client settings need to be updated to Microsoft Exchange. For more info see https://x.co/client'

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Plesk hosting account allows sending e-mails to external e-mail servers via its own relay server (Detail is explained [here](https://community.godaddy.com/s/question/0D53t00006VmEIvCAN/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissions-17319479109) by JesseW under GoDaddy's q/a portal). So when I changed my code as following the problem is solved and now I can send e-mails again.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net ';
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';
$mail->Port = 25;


$mail->From = ('from@from.com');
$mail->addAddress('to@destination.com');
$mail->FromName = 'myname';
```

With relay mail server, port must be set to 25, Host must be changed as `relay-hosting.secureserver.net`[See link](https://www.godaddy.com/help/send-form-mail-using-an-smtp-relay-server-953) and SSL or Secure connection must be set to none.

Before that I have tried multiple servers (including office365 and exchange), multiple ports including 25 (with other hosts such as office365 etc.), 3535, 80, 465 and multiple SMTP Secure types, visited Azure, Office365 and GoDaddy Admin panels and changed SMTP Auth settings but none of them worked. The only problem with current configuration might be security-wise. I will look for secure access with ssl and tls settings next.

But at least code is now functional and working again.